# How to restore a hard drive from a usb disk image using ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-8, hard-drive

As a result of a series of events to convoluted to get into, I have a 128gb flashdrive with a windows 7 system disk image on it and a harddrive that I would like to restore it to. That harddrive is currently connected to a Ubuntu computer running 14.04.1 (via SATA). I also have a laptop running windows 8.

So, is it possible with this equipment the I can somehow restore my hard drive?

Comment: I also cannot attach the hard drive to my laptop

Comment: Is there anything you want to recover from the hard drive or can it be formatted? You would probably need to reinstall Windows on it and then use a System Repair Disc to restore the image.

Comment: the hard  drive is  new, so empty - I was originally upgrading from a smaller hard drive to a bigger hard drive.

Comment: Do you have a copy of Windows to install on the empty drive? Or a repair disc to use?

Comment: I have an xp disc, although the not even sure it can run on my desktop

Comment: the winxp disc is good to go. fortunately

Comment: I'm not sure if an XP disc can recover a Windows 7 image.

Comment: do you know if there is any Ubuntu tool that can do the trick?